# How do I clean my drive train?

Tags: maintenance, drivetrain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to use to clean your chain (and cogs)?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-to-use-to-clean-your-chain-and-cogs)

My mountain bike drive train has accumulated a dirt /oil layer from oiling the chain and then ridding in dirt and muck.

How do I safely clean my chain and gear so I can put a fresh coat of chain oil on?

Comment: Check out this question:  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-to-use-to-clean-your-chain-and-cogs

Comment: as darkcanuck pointed out, this question is a duplicate of an existing question... more or less. One suggestion: You might consider making this more mountain-bike specific, to differentiate it from the other cleaning question. (That question asks about what to use to get the grease off, but the accepted answer is really a good how-to-clean guide.)